# Wordpress Plugin to identify what php code a page use

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm looking a plugin that allow me to know/identify when I am in a page the php classes used in that page.

For example, a page can be part of a plugin or a part of a template,
so if I have to change it how can I know where I need to change the code among the many php classes?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set on your wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

It will enable the “debug” mode throughout WordPress.

When set to "true", you’ll start seeing PHP notices, WordPress-generated debug messages, deprecated function usage, etc.

If this is not enough for you, you can try this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-my-plugin/

Comment: Where I'll start see PHP notices?

I cant find it after I enabled WP_DEBUG

Comment: You'll see. All notices will appear in html. But If you want to write those notices to a logfile, just set `define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);` then it will record your notices under /wp-content/debug.log

Comment: ok you're right. Thanks so much.

Debug Bar dont show anything in my page.

Do you know alternative?